# How to avoid rounding for long decimal numbers in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to print the first 200 decimal digits of the number **1/998,001**. If I run the following code

```
print("{:10.200f}".format(1/998001))
```

the result I obtain is rounded

> 0.00000100200300400500595528706631459625597813101194333285093307495117187500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

How can I obtain the precise result instead?

Comment: Worth noting in passing that the rounding that is going on here is to the nearest binary value at some level of precision, and occurs far earlier than the number of non-zero decimal digits might suggest. Compare the value shown above with that in the accepted answer, and see where they start to differ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module for this

```
import decimal
with decimal.localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.prec = 200
    d = decimal.Decimal(1.0) / 998001

>>> d
Decimal('0.0000010020030040050060070080090100110120130140150160170180190200210220230240250260270280290300310320330340350360370380390400410420430440450460470480490500510520530540550560570580590600610620630640650660671')
```

Comment: Not like that though. You mean `d = decimal.Decimal(1.0) / 998001`. You are using ordinary floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Suitably corrected, have an up vote... for anyone reading this now that it's been edited, the context was `decimal.Decimal(1.0 / 998001)`

Comment: Note that this code changes the global decimal context, which will lead to surprising results if any other part of the code also uses Decimal numbers. If possible, use [`with decimal.localcontext() as ctx`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.localcontext) to adjust the precision just for each part of the code that needs it.

Comment: @sabik That is a good suggestion, let me adjust my answer.

Comment: A couple of years ago I saw two projects being combined and a bunch of unit tests started failing because one of them changed the decimal context globally, including for the tests for the other...